# How can i use get request using httpClient java without get content?

Tags: java, httpclient

I want to get request a page to set parameters using url(example.com?x=ttt&y=zzz) to reserve those in target server and then should do post request after that final. how can i do these (get request and then post request) in 1 seconds or faster way.
is there any way to do get and post together? but i should get first then post...

Comment: Do it all in the POST. Unclear why you are even considering a two-part solution.

Comment: I have to send some parameters using GET request to external server then finish that request using another POST